# Subsetting a dataframe conditionally by comparing it with a different nrow dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the rows of a dataframe which present some common data with the rows of a different size dataframe:

```
df1: 

A   B   C   D
a   t   4   9
s   p   3   7
w   d   1   10

df2:
A   B   C   D
a   t   3   7
m   r   5   8
p   m   1   3
g   u   5   2
s   p   2   6
```

I am trying to get the rows of df1 accomplishing this conditions:
1. A and B variables must be equal between both dataframes
2. df1$C must belong to the interval (df2$C -5, df2$C +5), so the absolute value of the different between both values must be less than 5.

```
new_df<-df1[df1$A == df2$A && df1$B == df2$B && (df1$C > (df2$C - 5) && df1$C < (df2$C + 5)), ]
```

But I am getting this error, because the number of rows of both dataframes are different:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried to use `which` but I am getting the same error. How can I solve this?

My expected output would be:

```
new_df

A   B   C   D
a   t   4   9
s   p   3   7
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah I want the number in df1$C is in the interval (df2$C - 5  ---  df2$C + 5); so I don't mind if this number is not exactly the same, but I want that the absolute value of the difference between both values be less than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly one way (deliberately made more intermediate variables here, it can be shortened). My logic was that `A` and `B` matching can be used to join the df's (step1 - resulting in the data frame `s1`) and then further filter on the numeric conditions (step2 - resulting in the data frame `s2`):

```r
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,
"a",  "t",  4,   9,
"s",  "p" , 3,   7,
"w",  "d",  1,   10
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,
"a", "t", 3 ,  7,
"m", "r",  5,   8,
"p", "m", 1 ,  3,
"g", "u",  5,   2,
"s", "p", 2 ,  6)

new_df<-df1[df1$A == df2$A && df1$B == df2$B && (df1$C > (df2$C - 5) && df1$C < (df2$C + 5)), ]

s1 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = (c("A", "B")),  suffix = c(".from1", ".from2"))
s2 <- s1 %>% 
  mutate(condition1 = C.from1 > C.from2 - 5,
         condition2 = C.from1 < C.from2 + 5) %>% 
  filter(condition1, condition2) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("condition"))
```

Comment: Could you tell me what's the meaning of  `select(-starts_with("condition"))`?

Comment: Oh, that’s just to remove the ‘condition’ columns from the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

Merging the 2 DF by *A* and *B* makes sure that these variables already match and assign it to a new DF.
In this new DF, apply the remaining 2 conditions and delete the last two columns which came from the merge.

```r
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,
"a",  "t",  4,   9,
"s",  "p" , 3,   7,
"w",  "d",  1,   10
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,
"a", "t", 3 ,  7,
"m", "r",  5,   8,
"p", "m", 1 ,  3,
"g", "u",  5,   2,
"s", "p", 2 ,  6)

merge(df1, df2, by = c('A', 'B')) -> df3
df3[(df3$C.x > df3$C.y-5) && df3$C.x < (df3$C.y + 5),][,-c(5,6)]
#>   A B C.x D.x
#> 1 a t   4   9
#> 2 s p   3   7
```